# Set DocumentViewer.Document from another thread?

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a class with a method (CreateDocument) that fires an event at the end. The event args contain a FixedDocument. In my MainWindow code I try to set a DocumentViewer's Document like:

```
void lpage_DocCreated(object sender, LabelDocumentEventArgs e)
{
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
  {
    FixedDocument fd = e.doc;
    documentViewer1.Document = fd;
    documentViewer1.FitToWidth();
    return null;
  }), null);
}
```

I receive "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." on line documentViewer1.Document = fd;

I am able to update a progress bar in another event handler that the same method fires while it is working:

```
    Int32 progress = Int32.Parse(sender.ToString());
    progBar.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
        {
          progBar.Value = progress;
          return null;
        }), null);
```

I can't figure out why I can't set the document when I'm essentially doing the same type of thing when I set the progress bar value.

Answer (score 0):

The FixedDocument element also has thread-affinity. So if you are creating it in a separate thread than the documentViewer1, then you would get that exception.

Basically, anything that derives from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx) has a thread-affinity. [FixedDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument.aspx) derives from DispatcherObject, just like the viewer controls.